# javascript add new properties to an object

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have this object:

```
let obj1 = {
key1: 'value1',
key2: 'value2'
}
```

And I have a different object like this:

```
let obj2 = {
key3: 'value3',
key4: 'value4'
}
```

Is there a way of adding obj2 properties to obj1 and have this?

```
{
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2',
    key3: 'value3',
    key4: 'value4'
}
```

I currently have this working but would want to know if there is an easier way:

```
for (prop in obj2) {
        if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          obj1[prop] = obj2[prop];
        }
      }
```

Comment: actually there are several ways on of them is obj1 = Object.assign(obj1, obj2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way of achieving this is using [Object's assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
Object.assign(obj1, obj2);
```

where the first object (obj1) is the target and will get modified.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Object Spread](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) , you could do it this way :

```
let mergedObjects = {...obj1, ...obj2};
```

Comment: This is very easy to use as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
let obj1 = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2'
}

let obj2 = {
  key3: 'value3',
  key4: 'value4'
}


console.log(Object.assign(obj1, obj2))
```